# Pandas: Sort innermost column group-wise based on other multilevel column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Consider below df:

```
In [3771]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a'] * 11,
               'B': ['b'] * 11,
               'C': ['C1', 'C1', 'C2','C1', 'C3', 'C3', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3', 'C2', 'C2'],
               'D': ['D1', 'D2', 'D1', 'D3', 'D3', 'D2', 'D4', 'D4', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
               'E': [{'value': '4', 'percentage': None}, {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}, {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}, {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}, {}, {'value': 19, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}, np.nan],
               'F':[{'value': 72, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 62, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 16,      'percentage': None}, {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 54, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 78, 'percentage': None}]})

In [3779]: df
Out[3898]: 
    A  B   C   D                                     E                                  F
0   a  b  C1  D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
1   a  b  C1  D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
2   a  b  C2  D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
3   a  b  C1  D3      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 62, 'percentage': None}
4   a  b  C3  D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
5   a  b  C3  D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 16, 'percentage': None}
6   a  b  C2  D4                                    {}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
7   a  b  C3  D4     {'value': 19, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
8   a  b  C3  D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
9   a  b  C2  D2     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 54, 'percentage': None}
10  a  b  C2  D3                                   NaN  {'value': 78, 'percentage': None}
```

I `pivot` the above df:

```
In [3776]: x = df.pivot(['B', 'C', 'D'], 'A', ['E', 'F'])

In [3781]: x
Out[3900]: 
                                            E                                  F
A                                           a                                  a
B C  D                                                                          
b C1 D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
     D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 62, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D2     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 54, 'percentage': None}
     D3                                   NaN  {'value': 78, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 16, 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D4     {'value': 19, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
```

I want to sort the innermost column which is `D` for each group of outer columns `B` and `C` based on the multi-level column with index `(E, a)` in descending order based on `value` key from dict.

**EDIT:**

The `dict` can have `value` key with mixed datatypes. It can be int, str, NaN or simply unavailable.

**Expected Output:**

```
                                            E                                  F
A                                           a                                  a
B C  D                                                                          
b C1 D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 62, 'percentage': None}
     D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D2     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 54, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
     D3                                   NaN  {'value': 78, 'percentage': None}
  C3 D4     {'value': 19, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}
     D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}  {'value': 16, 'percentage': None}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with helper `MultiIndex column` created by [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), then sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove helper column:

```
x[('new', 'a')] = pd.to_numeric(x[('E','a')].str.get('value'), errors='coerce')
lvl = x.index.names[:-1]

order = 'desc'

x = (x.sort_values(lvl + [('new', 'a')],ascending=[True] * len(lvl) + [order == 'asc'])
       .drop(('new', 'a'), axis=1))
```

---

```
print (x)

                                            E  \
A                                           a   
B C  D                                          
b C1 D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}   
     D3      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}   
     D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}   
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}   
     D2     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}   
     D3                                   NaN   
     D4                                    {}   
  C3 D4     {'value': 19, 'percentage': None}   
     D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}   
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}   
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}   

                                         F  
A                                        a  
B C  D                                      
b C1 D2  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}  
     D3  {'value': 62, 'percentage': None}  
     D1  {'value': 72, 'percentage': None}  
  C2 D1  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}  
     D2  {'value': 54, 'percentage': None}  
     D3  {'value': 78, 'percentage': None}  
     D4  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}  
  C3 D4  {'value': 67, 'percentage': None}  
     D1  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}  
     D3  {'value': 66, 'percentage': None}  
     D2  {'value': 16, 'percentage': None}
```

Comment: do you know why this soultion produces an error?    `x.sort_values(by=('E', 'a'), key=lambda x: x.get('value'))`

or the equivalent `x.sort_values(by=('E', 'a'), key=lambda x: x['value'])`

Comment: @IoaTzimas - Maybe new functionality, so some bugs.

Comment: @jezrael Can you please make this solution a bit general in the sense where I don't have to hardcode name of the columns `B` , `C` and `D`? I always need to sort the innermost column which is `D`, and rest of the columns(`B` and `C`) can be same.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the help. There's one more case, should I add sample data for it?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - answer was edited with convert values to numeric.

Comment: @jezrael I would be receiving `('E','a')` in a parameter. Is there any way to not use `('new', 'a')`, as I won't be knowing if there's `a` in my column?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - `a` is any value, not important here ;)

Comment: You can chnage `a` to `any value` ;)

Comment: Ok. Also `sort_order` is a parameter that I will receive with values either `desc` or `asc`. How will I sort in either order?

Comment: @jezrael This works really well. Thankyou for all the help.