# Pandas: Sort innermost column group-wise based on other multilevel column excluding one row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

This is an extension to my [`previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021214/pandas-sort-innermost-column-group-wise-based-on-other-multilevel-column):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [68]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a'] * 11,
    ...:                'B': ['b'] * 11,
    ...:                'C': ['C1', 'C1', 'C2','C1', 'C3', 'C3', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3', 'C2', 'C2'],
    ...:                'D': ['D1', 'D2', 'D1', 'D3', 'D3', 'D2', 'D4', 'D4', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
    ...:                'E': [{'value': '4', 'percentage': None}, {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}, {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}, {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}, {}, {'valu
    ...: e': 24, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}, {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}]})
    ...:
```

`Pivot` of above df:

```
In [69]: x = df.pivot(['B', 'C', 'D'], 'A', ['E'])

In [70]: x
Out[70]: 
                                            E
A                                           a
B C  D                                       
b C1 D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}
     D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}
     D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}
```

I want to sort the innermost column which is `D` for each group of outer columns `B and C` based on the multi-level column with index `(E, a)` in `asc/desc` order based on `value` key from dict.

But, for every group there would be a row with the `total` value of all other rows. I always need to keep that row at the last irrespective of sorting order(asc or desc).

**Expected output in case of `desc`**:

```
Out[70]: 
                                            E
A                                           a
B C  D                                       
b C1 D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}
     D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}
```

**Expected output in case of `asc`**:

```
Out[70]: 
                                            E
A                                           a
B C  D                                       
b C1 D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}
     D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}
     D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}
```

Comment: It's challenging due to your data structure. You have dictionaries inside dataframe, which is generally discouraged. Not to mention you want to sum the values inside the dictionaries, which are sometimes strings, sometimes integers. It's better you just make a `for` loop.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't want to sum anything here. Its just kind of sorting the whole `df` based on a column. The sorting logic is mostly answered in the linked [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021214/pandas-sort-innermost-column-group-wise-based-on-other-multilevel-column). Please have a look at it. I just want to keep the row with `total` at last always for each group.

Comment: Yes, I misread, but sorting is pretty much the same story.

Comment: I'am able to solve this using @jezrael's answer per last question. But its a bit clumsy. So I was looking for a better approach.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Can the `value`  key in dictionary contains negative value?

Comment: No, it cannot have negative value.

Comment: Ok. Sharing. Sending you a link. Please check [this](https://ibb.co/80dwdL2).

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Thank you.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - answer is ready, only add some decrpition

Comment: @jezrael Great thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with helper columns used for sorting - first convert `values` to numeric columns by [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) and [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and then create another column compared max value per groups for boolean:

```
lvls = list(x.index.names[:-1])
print (lvls)
['B', 'C']

x[('tmp', 'tmp')] = pd.to_numeric(x[('E','a')].str.get('value'), errors='coerce')

x[('max','tmp')] = x.groupby(lvls)[[('tmp','tmp')]].transform('max') == x[[('tmp','tmp')]]
```

All values in ascending parameter are `True`, default value:

```
x1 = x.sort_values(lvls + [('max','tmp'), ('tmp','tmp')])
print (x1)
                                            E   tmp    max
A                                           a   tmp    tmp
B C  D                                                    
b C1 D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}   4.0  False
     D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}   5.0  False
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}   9.0   True
  C2 D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}  11.0  False
     D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D4                                    {}   NaN  False
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}  33.0   True
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}   NaN  False
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}  24.0   True
```

Here is changed last `True` to `False`:

```
x2 = x.sort_values(lvls + [('max','tmp'), ('tmp','tmp')],
                   ascending=[True] * len(lvls) + [True, False])
print (x2)
```

---

```
                                            E   tmp    max
A                                           a   tmp    tmp
B C  D                                                    
b C1 D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}   5.0  False
     D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}   4.0  False
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}   9.0   True
  C2 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}  11.0  False
     D4                                    {}   NaN  False
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}  33.0   True
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}  12.0  False
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}   NaN  False
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}  24.0   True
```

Last remove helper columns:

```
x1 = x1.drop([('max','tmp'), ('tmp','tmp')], axis=1)
x2 = x2.drop([('max','tmp'), ('tmp','tmp')], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thankyou.

Comment: I have another use-case here, can I add sample data now?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Really complicated, rather new question please.

Comment: Sure @jezrael. I'll post a new one soon. Gimme 10 mins.

Comment: Please check [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217755/pandas-sort-innermost-column-group-wise-based-on-a-multilevel-column-excluding).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that `groups` the multilevel column `E, a` on levels `B and C` and returns the indices that would sort the dataframe as specified by the rule where the row with the total value of all other rows is kept at last:

```
def sort_idx(s):
    idx = []
    for k, g in s.groupby(level=[0, 1], sort=False):
        i = g.idxmax()
        idx += [*g.drop(i).sort_values().index , i]
    return idx

s = pd.to_numeric(x[('E', 'a')].str['value'], errors='coerce')
x = x.loc[sort_idx(s)]
```

Result:

```
                                            E
A                                           a
B C  D                                       
b C1 D1    {'value': '4', 'percentage': None}
     D2      {'value': 5, 'percentage': None}
     D3      {'value': 9, 'percentage': None}
  C2 D3     {'value': 11, 'percentage': None}
     D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D4                                    {}
     D2     {'value': 33, 'percentage': None}
  C3 D1     {'value': 12, 'percentage': None}
     D3   {'value': '12', 'percentage': None}
     D2  {'value': 'N/A', 'percentage': None}
     D4     {'value': 24, 'percentage': None}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shubham. But, if you see in the 2nd group, row with `33` should come at last, and row with `{}` should be above it. Please check my expected output for both cases(asc and desc).

Comment: @MayankPorwal Ahh okay! i missed that part :)

Comment: @MayankPorwal Edited the answer.